# How to easier manipulate timespan in powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, time, timespan

I am doing an assignment for Powershell and one of the functions is to say when the last boot was. I am printing date and 'time since', date works fine but I think there is too much code for displaying the 'time since'. I want the first value to not be zero. Like this:

> 1 Hour, 0 Minutes, 34 Seconds

and not like this:

> 0 Days, 1 Hours, 0 Minutes, 34 Seconds

```
$bootDate = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
$bootTime = $(Get-Date).Subtract($bootDate)
# Think there is an easier way, but couldn't find any :/
$time = ""
if($bootTime.Days -ne 0) {
  $time = "$($bootTime.Days) Days, $($bootTime.Hours) Hours, $($bootTime.Minutes) Minutes, "
} elseif($bootTime.Hours -ne 0){
    $time = "$($bootTime.Hours) Hours, $($bootTime.Minutes) Minutes, "
} elseif($bootTime.Minutes -ne 0){
    $time = "$($bootTime.Minutes) Minutes, "
}
echo "Time since last boot: $time$($bootTime.Seconds) Seconds"
echo "Date and time:        $($bootDate.DateTime)"
```

This code prints it as I want it to be, but is just seems like too much code for something so little. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I like your solution as-is (minor formatting issues).  The strings are descriptive and does not have unneeded array string copies.  Put it in a function, then re-use it as needed.  Welcome to StackOverflow btw.  See also `"{0:hh} hours, {0:dd} days, {0:mm} minutes" -f $bootTime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you inspect to `TotalDays` rather than `Days`. Additionally, I would split the code into a separate function:

```
function Get-TruncatedTimeSpan {
  param([timespan]$TimeSpan)

  $time = ""

  if($TimeSpan.TotalDays -ge 1) {
    $time += "$($TimeSpan.Days) Days, "
  } 
  if($TimeSpan.TotalHours -ge 1){
    $time += "$($TimeSpan.Hours) Hours, "
  } 
  if($TimeSpan.TotalMinutes -ge 1){
    $time += "$($TimeSpan.Minutes) Minutes, "
  }
  return "$time$($TimeSpan.Seconds) Seconds"
}

$bootDate = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
$bootTime = $(Get-Date).Subtract($bootDate)

echo "Time since last boot: $(Get-TruncatedTimeSpan $bootTime)"
echo "Date and time:        $($bootDate.DateTime)"
```

Comment: Days instead of TotalDays (similarly with the other fields) is a really common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

A concise solution based on removing the longest run of `0`-valued components from the start, using the `-replace` operator, which uses a regular expression for matching (and by not specifying a replacement string effectively *removes* the match):

```
function get-FriendlyTimespan {
  param([timespan] $TimeSpan)
  "{0} Days, {1} Hours, {2} Minutes, {3} Seconds" -f
    $TimeSpan.Days, $TimeSpan.Hours, $TimeSpan.Minutes, $TimeSpan.Seconds -replace
      '^0 Days, (0 Hours, (0 Minutes, )?)?'
}

# Invoke with sample values (using string-based initialization shortcuts):
"0:0:1", "0:1:0", "1:0:0", "1", "0:2:33" | % { get-FriendlyTimespan $_ }
```

The above yields:

```
1 Seconds
1 Minutes, 0 Seconds
1 Hours, 0 Minutes, 0 Seconds
1 Days, 0 Hours, 0 Minutes, 0 Seconds
2 Minutes, 33 Seconds
```

Comment: ...and now you have two problems.

Comment: It's just an [old joke](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) about Regular Expressions

Comment: @Dinei: I see, thanks for teaching me the history. So, are _you_ just joking, or do you see a problem with the answer?

Comment: I don't see any issues with the specific Regex you posted. But, as always, regexes' bugs tend to be the worst to locate and solve, so my recommendation would be to avoid them where they're not necessary.

Comment: @Dinei: While regexes can be a nightmare, to me this specific solution is concise, conceptually clear and therefore maintainable. I hope others find it useful too.